# Celery synchronous task on specific worker by queue name in Django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two workers one with a default queue and one with a named queue. I want to run a synchronous task on the worker with the named queue. However, the tasks seems to be always executed on the web thread of Django. The code is as follows:

file1.py:

```
from test.task import predict
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class run(APIView):
  def get(self, request, age):
    result = predict.apply(args=[age])
    print(result.get())
    return Response({})
```

task.py

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(queue="gpu")
def predict(age):
    result = age + 1   
    return result
```

When I read the documentation correctly this should run on the worker started like this:

> celery -A main worker --loglevel=info -n worker-gpu@%h -Q gpu

But it seems never to run there. Can someone explain how I can force the task to run synchronously on the the worker with the gpu queue?